# Probability with a uniform distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

A group of athletes have pulse rates uniformly distributed between 60 and 75. What is the probability that a randomly chosen member of the group has a pulse rate greater than 70?

I am thinking that because it is a uniform distribution, of interval length 15, that the probability would be $\frac{75-70}{15}=\frac{1}{3}$. Is it really that simple, or am I missing something hugely important?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's it.  Your probability distribution looks like a rectangle:  $1/15$ on the interval $[60, 75]$ and zero elsewhere.  Slice off the part to the right of $70$ and you get your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the answer would be 5/16.  There are 16 possible pulse rates 60 to 75 both included.  And we are looking at 5 desired pulse rates 71 to 75.  So the probability would be 5/16 not 1/3.  We are looking at discrete distribution as you can not have pulse rates like 60.5 and 70.9.

Comment: "you can not have pulse rates like 60.5 and 70.9" - why not? That's more of an artifact of how the rates are reported.